# how to use sequence for tokenazation but not returned as par of result

Tags: antlr4

I would like to use a rule or sequence as a separator to tokenize a file but not return the separator

I tried using `-> channel(hidden)` but that messes up the parsing

I  have a grammar such that

```
grammar test;

file
 : l1 l2? l3
;

l1
 : 'L1:' STRING_LITERAL '\n'
;
l2
 : 'L2:'(NUMBER)+ '\n'
;
l3
 :'L3:' WORD|NUMBER '\n'
;


NUMBER          : [0-9]+ ;
STRING_LITERAL  : '"' (~["\\\r\n] | EscapeSequence)* '"';
WORD            : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
fragment EscapeSequence
    : '\\' [btnfr"'\\]
    | '\\' ([0-3]? [0-7])? [0-7]
    ;
```

and an input file like

```
L1: "SO LONG"
L2: 42
L3: FISH
```

I'd like to not return `L1:` `L2:` and `L3:` but do return "SO LONG" `42` and `FISH`

I get the tokens I'm looking for but I also get `\n` `L1:` `L2:` and `L3:`

[image: See this for results tree]

Also I noticed that if I have l1 rule set as l1 : (~["\\r\n])* ; I can match till end of line no problem but I get every word as a separate token. This makes sense to me but is there a way to take it as a single token?

Comment: Also I noticed that if I have l1 rule set as

l1
 : (~["\\\r\n])*
;

I can match till end of line no problem but I get every word as a separate token. This makes sense to me but is there a way to take it as a single token?

Comment: Hi Demian, do not post additional info as comment but put them in the question =)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to use these `L1:` tokens inside the parser, then there's no way to remove them. I don't see a real use-case for that anyway. But, I don't see why you can't just skip (or hide) these tokens during the lexer. This seems to work just fine:

```
parse
 : NL* line ( NL+ line )* NL* EOF
 ;

line
 : l1
 | l2
 | l3
 ;

l1 : STRING_LITERAL;
l2 : NUMBER+;
l3 : ( WORD | NUMBER );

NUMBER         : [0-9]+;
STRING_LITERAL : '"' ( ~["\\\r\n] | EscapeSequence )* '"';
WORD           : [a-zA-Z]+;

IGNORED
 : 'L' [0-9] ':' -> skip
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t]+ -> skip
 ;

NL
 : '\r'? '\n'
 ;

fragment EscapeSequence
 : '\\' [btnfr"'\\]
 | '\\' ([0-3]? [0-7])? [0-7]
 ;
```

resulting in:

[image]

> [...] so I should be able to do something like if (parser.l1() == "SO LONG"") then do something

That is not how ANTLR works. The parser produces a parse tree (with all the tokens you defined). That parse tree can then be used to extract values from. Extracting values can be done by manually walking the parse tree, or by using ANTLR's listener (or visitor) class: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/listeners.md

This is my suggestion to you: do not `skip` the line break and `L1:` tokens from the lexer, and use a listener or visitor to retrieve the data from you parse tree.

Comment: Thanks Bart. The  use case is that the parser would already have a `parser.l1()` method and I 'd like it to just return the value. Essentially I'm thinking of this as a  key-value dictionary (perhaps this is the wrong way to see it?) so I should be able to do something like if (parser.l1() == "SO LONG"") then do something

Comment: Also similarly with the \n I'd like it to not be returned at all

Comment: You need the `\n` in the parser: it denotes the end of a line. Without it, you can't tell the difference between `L2: 123\nL2: 456\n` and `L2: 123 456\n`

Comment: ah I understand now. Thanks a lot for that @BartKiers !